# Use equivalence Theorems inside Greater Than Propositions in Coq

Tags: coq

I have the following operation definitions for Equivalence, Less Than and Addition in the context of natural numbers:

```
Require Import Setoid.

(* CNat Set *)
Parameter (CNat:Set) (O i:CNat).

(* CEq Equivalence *)
Parameter CEq: CNat->CNat->Prop.
Infix "¦" := CEq (at level 70, no associativity).
Axiom ceq_refl: forall x:CNat, x¦x.
Axiom ceq_sym: forall x y:CNat, x¦y->y¦x.
Axiom ceq_trans: forall x y z:CNat, x¦y->y¦z->x¦z.
Add Relation CNat CEq
  reflexivity proved by ceq_refl
  symmetry proved by ceq_sym
  transitivity proved by ceq_trans
  as ceq_rel.

(* CLe StrictOrder *)
Parameter CLe: CNat->CNat->Prop.
Infix "«" := CLe (at level 70).
Axiom cle_irrefl: forall x:CNat, ~x«x.
Axiom cle_trans: forall x y z:CNat, x«y->y«z->x«z.
Add Relation CNat CLe
  transitivity proved by cle_trans
  as cle_rel.

(* CAdd Operation *)
Parameter CAdd : CNat->CNat->CNat.
Infix "±" := CAdd (at level 50, left associativity).
Add Morphism CAdd with signature CEq ==> CEq ==> CEq 
  as ceq_add_mor. Admitted.
```

Then I define Neutral Addition and Natural Induction and try to use them inside a Test Theorem:

```
(* CNat Axioms *)
Axiom cnat_add_neutral: forall x:CNat, x±O¦x.
Axiom cnat_induction: forall P: CNat->Prop, P O ->
    (forall x:CNat, P x->P (x±i)) -> forall x:CNat, P x.

(* CNat Test Theorem *)
Example cle_neutral_test: forall x:CNat, O«x -> O«x±O.
Proof.
  intros x CH.
  rewrite cant_add_neutral. (* Error *)
  apply CH.
Qed.
```

With the following error:

```
Error:
Tactic failure: setoid rewrite failed: Unable to satisfy the following constraints:
In environment:
x : CNat
CH : O « x
do_subrelation := Morphisms.do_subrelation : Morphisms.apply_subrelation

?p : "Morphisms.Proper (CEq ==> Basics.flip Basics.impl) (CLe O)"
```

What kind of previous definition or demonstration should I generate before being able making this Test work?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the reason for choosing that symbol for `CEq`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Using more standard notation, I hope that's still clear to you. `CEq` is `==`, `CLe` is `<` (it should probably be named `CLt`))

First, before even delving into rewriting, let's make sure you logically have enough facts to prove the theorem.

You want to prove `x < y`, and you know `y == z`. For that you would want the following lemma, to change the goal to `x < z`:

```
y == z -> x < z -> x < y
```

This is presently missing from the list of facts.

One way to present that fact suitably for generalized rewriting is as a `Morphism` declaration for `CLe`:

```
Add Morphism CLe with signature CEq ==> CEq ==> iff
  as ceq_cle_mor. Admitted.
```

The signature `CEq ==> CEq ==> iff` means:

```
forall x x',
  x == x' ->
  forall y y',
  y == y' ->
  (x < y) <-> (x' < y')
```

Which one can easily check is a generalization of the missing fact above. Having added it, and after fixing a typo in the `cnat_add_neutral` lemma (in the initial version of your question, now edited), the proof goes through.

```
Add Morphism CLe with signature CEq ==> CEq ==> iff
  as ceq_cle_mor. Admitted.

(* CNat Test Theorem *)
Example cle_neutral_test: forall x:CNat, O«x -> O«x±O.
Proof.
  intros x CH.
  rewrite cnat_add_neutral.
  apply CH.
Qed.
```